# How to call Perl script in Django?

Tags: django

I have a backend program written in Perl (Simple Hello world). I am new to Django.

I want to interact this helloworld.pl with Django, the action should be something like,
when I click on login button it must process the helloworld.pl file and display Helloworld on page.

Comment: Why not write the hello world code in Python/Django? It doesn't really make sense, unless the Perl script has unique functionality that you really need.

Comment: You can use the os.system method to run the perl file(assuming it's in the same directory).

Comment: Actually , some big code are written in Perl only, so i just wanted to know how can i call any Perl script in Django application. I have created simple login page when I press login button the Perl script function must get executed.......So that i can call all my perl script in django

Comment: Hey Pramod, Can u give example by using simple perl script .....>?Pls

Comment: here is example of calling PHP file, like this i want to call perl file.                                                          import subprocess

#simple caller, disguard output

subprocess.call("php /path/to/my/old/script.php")

# if you want output

proc = subprocess.Popen("php /path/to/my/script.php", shell=True,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

script_response = proc.stdout.read()

Answer (score 2):

You can refer my blog for detailed explanation >>

http://www.easyaslinux.com/tutorials/devops/how-to-run-execute-any-script-python-perl-ruby-bash-etc-from-django-views/

I would suggest you to use Popen method of Subprocess module. Your shell script can be executed as system command with Subprocess.

Here is a little help.

Your **views.py** should look like this.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from django.http import HttpResponse

def main_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            command = ["perl","your_script_path.pl"]
            try:
                    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
                    output = process.stdout.read()
                    exitstatus = process.poll()
                    if (exitstatus==0):
                            result = {"status": "Success", "output":str(output)}
                    else:
                            result = {"status": "Failed", "output":str(output)}

            except Exception as e:
                    result =  {"status": "failed", "output":str(e)}

            html = "<html><body>Script status: %s \n Output: %s</body></html>" %(result['status'],result['output'])
            return HttpResponse(html)
```

In this example, stderr and stdout of the script is saved in variable '*output*', And exit code of the script is saved in variable '*exitstatus*'.

Configure your **urls.py** to call the view function "*main_function*".

```
url(r'^the_url_to_run_the_script$', main_function)
```

Now you can run the script by calling *http://server_url/the_url_to_run_the_script*